# Assigned value in nested dict gets overridden in last loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a csv file that I want to transform into a nested Python dictionary, where the keys are the names and the values are nested dictionaries containing the keys hours and status (I will add additional keys later on). The csv file looks something like this:

```
Name,Hours,Status
John Doe,10,Done
Jane Doe,9,In Progress
Peter Johnson,8,In Progress
```

Unfortunately, whenever I'm looping over the csv file and assign a value to example[name]['Available Hours'], it overrides it with the value of the last person in the csv file:

```
import csv

template = {
        'Available Hours': None,
        'Project Status': None,
}

with open('example.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='\"')

    example = {}

    for row in csv_reader:
        name = row['Name']
        if name not in example.keys():
            example[name] = template

        # Add available hours to dict
        available_hours = row['Hours']
        example[name]['Available Hours'] = available_hours

        # Add project status to dict
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
{
'Jane Doe': {
    'Available Hours': '8',
    'Project Status': None
    },
'John Doe': {
    'Available Hours': '8',
    'Project Status': None
    },
'Peter Johnson': {
    'Available Hours': '8',
    'Project Status': None
    }
}
```

As you can see, each key-value pair for 'Hours' is now set to 8. Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `example[name] = template` doesn't make a *copy* of `template`, as you seem to expect - every item in your dictionary ends up referencing the template itself.  Try `example[name] = template.copy()` instead.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper, that solved it!